# What are JVM, execution, storage and, pool memories in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I take a non trivial dataframe (9.5 GB on disk) and add 1 and 2 to its one of the columns and then trigger the code using `foreach`

```
df_sales = df_sales.withColumns({'order_id_a1':df_sales.order_id+1,'order_id_a2':df_sales.order_id+2})

df_sales.foreach(lambda x:None)
```

Following is the executor level summary from the spark web UI

[image]

Questions:

1. Peak execution memory is defined as the *maximum memory used by the internal data structures created during shuffles, aggregations and joins.*? These internal data structures are hashmaps like AppendOnlyMap. I am adding 1 and 2 to a column. Which part of the memory is put to use to enable that addition? Also, What is execution memory offHeap?
2. Why is the Storage Memory getting used? I haven't called persist on anything. But then the documentation says that the storage memory is also used for propogating internal data across the cluster. What would be an example of that internal data in this case?
3. Which memory is the input utilizing? As you can see each executor is reading about 750 MiB of data. That is in partitions of 128 MiB blocks. There are execution, storage, reserved, offHeap and, overhead parts to the memory. Where do those 128 MiB blocks go to?
4. What is Peak JVM Memory? I think it might be max of JVM memory that was being put to work at any time. SO onHeap peak JVM memory = max(execution+storage+reserved) and, offHeap peak JVM memory = max(pyspark memory + offHeap + overhead). Am I correct? If so, then, how do we justify a peak onHeap of 1.1 GiB when Peak execution is 0, reserved is 300 and peak storage is 502.2KiB? It does not add up
5. What is Pool Memory? (Both Direct/Mapped)